# dynamic urls in php and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, url

how can I create a url that does not cause error even if a user changes some characters. for example **www.example.com/food/apple/** if someone changes it to **www.example.com/food/apple** it still loads on refresh or **www.example.com/food/app** it still loads on refresh or at least load **www.example.com/food/** on refresh

I tried a few .htaccess methods but none works for me
here is the one code that came close to what I am trying to do

```
  AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml

  # basic compression
 <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js)$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# Protect files and directories
<FilesMatch      
"\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?  
|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
 # Don’t show directory listings
 Options -Indexes
 # Basic rewrite rules, stop unneeded PERL bot, block subversion directories
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
  ErrorDocument 403 "Access Forbidden"
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
 RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

 # to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
 # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

 # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

  </IfModule>
```

however when the url goes from **www.example.com/food** to **www.example.com/food/apple** it throws a 500 Internal Server Error
**food** in this case is a file not a directory or folder. the file gathers information dynamically via urls. However when the extension is generated it throws an error.

Comment: The file food.php itself works?

Comment: yeah it generates info on click via url. however when the url extension appears I think the file is automatically redirected. So the 500 error pops up

Comment: h.owever on other pages the same error pops up so it is most likely the .htaccess not configured properly